# Best Approach to Group 500,000 Audio Files (Many Duplicates)?

Tags: audio, categories, similarity, audio-processing

I have a database of 500,000 user-uploaded audio files consisting of:

- Songs
- Audio clips from movies
- Random audio files from online
- User recorded audio clips (e.g. with a microphone)

The audio files are titled, albeit inconsistently and sometimes incorrectly.

There are many duplicates with slight differences: title differences, audio differences (length, compression, pitch, etc). I want to put each audio file into a category that corresponds to what it is. "What it is" means the most relevant title for that audio file based on the audio (not the title).

For example, there might be 30 different audio files for "Michael Jackson - Thriller" that are at slightly different lengths, compression levels, titled differently, etc. These should all be grouped into one category with a properly formatted title of the song.

Some audio files will be impossible to correctly title programmatically. For example the audio from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ee925OTFBCA will have many instances in the database, but I don't think there's an API out there that would be able to title it. In this case, provided they can still be matched as similar sounding and placed into one group, a title could be selected from the titles that the clips already have. I think I'd do this by working out the title that is the most "similar" to all of them (e.g. highest average Sørensen–Dice coefficient).

There is also a portion of user recorded clips that are impossible to title/group programmatically because they only exist within this database.

As an example of the inconsistent titling, Beethoven's Symphony No. 6 might have lots of different names like:

- Symphony No. 6 (Beethoven)
- Beethoven's Sixth Symphony
- Beethoven 6
- Beathoven sixth simphony (intentional spelling error)

To categorize these files, I am planning on doing the following for each:

- Use an audio recognition API to attempt to identify it, if it can be identified, place it in category
- If it can't be identified, check across database for audio clips that are very similar
- If there is a match in the audio database, link that audio clip to the match so it is placed in the same category as the matched audio clip (if the matched clip doesn't already have a category, then it will be when it is given one)
- If there isn't a match, place the file it its own category with its preexisting title

The objective of this is make the database smaller and better categorized so that it uses less storage space and is easier for end users to search and navigate.

Right now, searches for some audio clips turn up hundreds of the same file with slight differences. That's the main problem we're trying to solve.

I have three questions:

- Which audio recognition API would be best suited to identify audio files? Especially taking into consideration the types of clips that are being identified, and pricing
- Which API should be used to compare audio files to work out similarities? The size of the database that these will be compared against needs to be considered
- Is my methodology flawed in some way? If so, how would you approach this task?

Comment: FAISS is likely suitable for the comparison part https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss

Comment: Getting a concise description of an entire audio file is usually referred to as "Audio Fingerprinting". There are many companies that offer products and services for this. One of them is https://acoustid.biz/ which is also open source. Here is a good overview https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Fingerprinting

Answer (score 0):

Getting a concise description of an entire audio file is usually referred to as "Audio Fingerprinting".

There are many solutions out there. The MusicBrainz.org documentation has a [good overview](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Fingerprinting), both commercial products and open source projects. Their own most recent approach, which is also available as open source is [AcousticId](https://acoustid.biz).